# Upload to arduino C#

Tags: c#, cmd, arduino

I am trying to upload a `blink.hex` file to an Arduino through C# using this code:

```
                string Folder1 = @"C:\Program Files(x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude";
            string Folder2 = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf";
            string Hexpath = @"C:\VG-Break In\HEX\VBISU.ino.hex";
            string arg =
                "-C" + Folder2
                + "-v -patmega328p -carduino  -P" +
                 cmbports.SelectedText.ToString() +
                "-b115200 -D -Uflash:w:" + Hexpath + "i";

            Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude" ,arg);
```

But it doesn't upload. I just see that cmd blinks for a fraction of a second...

The line I see in my Arduino IDE when uploading is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM5 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\VICTOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_426502/VBISU.ino.hex:i
```

Comment: Why would you do this though? Is the Arduino IDE too complex for you? And for a tiny task like this, a batch/shell script would do better.

Answer (score 0):

You look to be squishing all your arguments together in the `arg` string. You need to separate them with spaces. What you have using the code you've shown is:

```
avrdude -CC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf-v -patmega328p -carduino  -Pport-b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\VG-Break In\HEX\VBISU.ino.hexi
```

not sure if your version needs a space between the option and its data but you definitely need to separate each individual option. You also forgot the ':' between the Hexpath and the type identifier 'i'.
Try the following:

```
string arg = "-C " + Folder2
             + " -v -p atmega328p -c arduino"
             + " -P " + cmbports.SelectedText.ToString()
             + " -b 115200 -D -U flash:w:" + Hexpath + ":i";
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my own question now after a bit of research and thought I would place the answer here if someone needs it. The problem where that I were trying to upload a file that the Arduino compiler had produced that did not have the Bootloader inlcuded. However I found out that the compiler also produced a file with the Bootloader included. When changing Hexpath to this file everything worked.

Comment: Answer box is for answer. You can ether comment anything on your own question or edit the question if you need to add some extra information.

Comment: I answered my own question to help other people with the same issue.